# Vectorizing subscript to matrix conversion

Tags: matlab

Given two vectors r and c that hold row and column subscripts into a matrix A (its size also given), I want to compute A. Points can occur multiple times and should increment the corresponding element in A for every occurence. An example:

```
r = [1 2 4 3 2];
c = [2 2 1 1 2];
A = zeros(4, 3);

ind = sub2ind(size(A), r, c);
for i = 1 : length(ind)
    A(ind(i)) = A(ind(i)) + 1; % could as well use r and c instead of ind ...
end
```

This yields the matrix

```
A =
     0     1     0
     0     2     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
```

I'd like to avoid the loop if possible. Is there a vectorized solution to this problem? Preferably one that does not generate huge temporary matrices ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for `accumarray`:

```
r = [1 2 4 3 2];
c = [2 2 1 1 2];

%# for every r,c pair, sum up the occurences
%# the [4 3] is the array size you want
%# the zero is the value you want where there is no data
accumarray([r',c'],ones(length(r),1),[4 3],@sum,0)

ans =

     0     1     0
     0     2     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
```

Note that if your resulting array has so many zeros (i.e. is very sparse), `sparse` may be the better option, as suggested by @woodchips

```
sparse(r,c,ones(size(r)),4,3)

ans =

   (3,1)        1
   (4,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (2,2)        2
```

Comment: +1 because this is an effective answer, but the question still highlights Matlab's extreme weakness when it comes to evaluating arrays at desired indices. The only reason that a simple call to `A(ind) += 1;` doesn't work is because the array of indices requests two accesses to the entry at (2,2), and Matlab cannot do this in a single call. Imagine if instead of merely incrementing these indices, the OP wanted to do a complicated operation at these places. Your answer works, but I think it doesn't get at the spirit of the question.

Comment: @EMS: What kind of more complex operation would you have wanted to perform?

Comment: Suppose `A` was a 3D array instead of 2D, and the depth dimension was RGB values. It would make sense to index a lot of things based on just the two-dimensional array of pixels. Then let's say I run a classifier cascade over the image and record the (i,j) locations where the classifier cascade "fires" to signal a detection. This can happen multiple times at the same pixel, so it could plausibly give the sort of repeated index lists in the OP's question.

Comment: Often, I want to apply feature extraction around these selected indices. So I may want to compute a local gradient, threshold it, and then put it into angle/magnitude bins, and return a histogram vector in the tiny region around the indexed pixel. The precise histogram may be different if different classifiers in the cascade had "fired" for a given pixel. In Python, for example, I can easily do this with `map()` and list comprehensions. In Matlab, it's a real pain.

Comment: @EMS: I guess you know that you can have `accumarray` return cells, or that its second argument can be indices that allow you to access more interesting stuff from the function handle, but in general I agree that working with RGB images can be a pain in Matlab.

Comment: Sparse may be a better choice than accumarray here, as the result will be a sparse matrix.

Comment: @woodchips: Good point, though I suspect that the OP may not have wanted to type out their possibly very long list of row/col indices.

Comment: @Jonas - and why would one possibly need to type out a list of row/column indices to use sparse? If you can use accumarray, then you can use the function sparse!

Comment: @woodchips: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I assumed that the OP usually deals with many more row/col indices. However, when creating the example, the OP didn't want to type out too long a list of numbers. In other words, while the array in the example is clearly sparse, the real life problem may not be.

Comment: Jonas, that's a nice one-liner, but horribly slow as soon as vectors and matrices are getting larger. I noticed that it's less horrible if the @sum,0 part is dropped -- it's not required anyway since accumarray sets elements without reference in [r',c'] to zero by default. From a performance point of view I should (surprisingly) stick with the FOR loop. Using accumarray, however, seems more concise.

Comment: @AtzeKaputtnik: Thanks for the update. Indeed, the question loop or no loop from a performance perspective can only really be answered by testing - and the answer may be different depending on the release. `bsxfun` used to be slower than the corresponding loop, until they multi-threaded it, for example.